# Are there any good Stack Exchange sites for daily life questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I sometimes want to ask questions about daily life in Germany, like a certain service, bank, location, strategy, etc, on the [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) but it gets closed because it’s not about life in Germany in general, just for specifically expat-related questions.

Has anyone considered making an everyday life Stack Exchange for questions like, “Which bank in Germany can be signed up for online rather than in person?”

Comment: There have been a few proposals for this sort of site on Area51 over the years.  None have got anywhere.  One problem is questions like your bank example would just attract spam answers and/or the answers would become obsolete rapidly.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, the problem with such a site would be that, while it may be doable to define a precise scope, it would be difficult to attract a group of experts being able to answer all these questions, because they can vary so much.

Instead, you could check the community about the related subject. Your question is similar to [Bank account in Germany for non-residents?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/24456/27340) on Personal Finance & Money. Are you having a Germany-specific problem with your bicycle (maybe for obtaining a special replacement part or something)? Head over to [Bicycles Stack Exchange](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/).